# I want to access local server with port to get json as respose

Tags: android, http, android-volley, port

I want to get json response from local server. I want to add port in that. how to add port while using volley in android

In main activity

```
{
    String url = "192.2.3.1:80/data";

    sendAndRequestResponse(url, new VolleyCallback(){
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(JSONObject result){

        }
    });
}

private void sendAndRequestResponse(final String url, final VolleyCallback callback) {

    //RequestQueue initialized
    mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this, new ProxyPort());

    //String Request initialized
    mStringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Response :" + response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();//display the response on screen
            Log.e("url", url);
            Log.e("Response", response.toString());

            try {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                callback.onSuccess(obj);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            Log.i("ERR", "Error :" + error.toString());
        }
    });
    VolleyLog.DEBUG = true;
    mRequestQueue.add(mStringRequest);
}
```

> I want to add port in this url. I want to access local host using ip. How to achieve it

Comment: If your server is localhost, then run the app on your emulator.

Comment: I want to run my app in device. I have to change port using edittext. that I can do. but don't know how to add port in that

Comment: You have add port 80 (80=http) in this url '192.2.3.1:80/data' 192.2.3.1:4711/data this will be port 4711

Comment: that's what I don't know how to add. I don't know where to add too. I have added http://192.2.3.1:80/data.. I want to add different port in future too.